# Track events in AMP-HTML (gallery events, videos events and others users interaction events)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking, amp-html

Integration with Analytics platform is made ​​by pixel counter. How metrics related to events are obtained? 
For example :

- View images from a gallery (amp-img);
- Interactions with the buttons of audio/video players (amp-video e amp-audio);
- And other user interactions.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the AMP Analytics design doc: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-analytics/amp-analytics.md which shows how to set up triggers so that you can get analytics events for specific Javascript events.

You should also follow the Github issue: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/871 where the design and implementation of the analytics framework are being discussed.